# How to add multiple members in MS Teams using Azure logic app

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps

I am using Azure logic app to post a message and call to Microsoft Teams. I am able to add a single user in MS Teams using "Add a member to a team" step in logic-app. For that I have created a parameter and inside a parameter I am adding an email address of a single user.

Now, I want to add multiple members in MS Teams instead of only single user but I did not find any option to add multiple members. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: You can use the for loop of the input list of the user and add to the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an [array object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values#initialize-variable) with your team members, then [loop over](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops) that array in the Logic App to add members the same way you are adding a single member.